# Console.log appears only after refresh

Tags: node.js, express, console.log

I have been working on a project with expressjs and ejs running inside docker-compose environment, I have this part where :

```
...

let server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port : ${port}!`);
});

...
```

I logged the console everytime I started the server, but I realized that the browser needed to be refreshed for it to be logged, whereas when I first started the log would showup directly after I started the server.

Before refresh: 
[image: click here]

After refresh:
[image: click here]

I would like to know if this is caused by all the other middlewares I have running before the server and if this is normal?

Here is the full link for my server.js : https://github.com/jumping-dragon/tiger/blob/master/server.js

Comment: `let server = app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Server started on port : ${port}!`);
});` shift this to before your routes

Comment: @Shubh tried it just now, same result. :'(

Comment: Are you use Windows terminal? If true, this is a issue of windows terminal, focus to the terminal and press 'Enter'.

Comment: @hoangdv this is through a mac terminal which is actually showing the logs from my docker, running nodejs, I'm not so sure if I can press 'Enter' on my terminal.